# How to get database messages while executing any query from Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Is it possible to get database console messages using JDBC after a query is being executed?

```
select * from staff
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you believe that is a "database message"? It's a message created by the *tool* you're using. --- For a `SELECT` you get the actual rows, so count them yourself. For `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements, the `executeUpdate()` method returns the count.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  For the number of rows affected, `executeUpdate` will return the number of rows affected, if the JDBC driver supports it.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is: No, it is not possible to get database console messages via JDBC.  Not server side or client side messages.   But think Andreas is correct.  That's not a "database console message" anyway.  (And it is not possible to get that *message* via JDBC either.)

Answer (score 1):

While executing any query from Java, except that it returns an integer value that reports the number of rows affected by the SQL statement.

Small example to understand

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement(  );
int  returnResult= stmt.executeUpdate("delete student"); 
System.out.ptintln("Affected rows "+returnResult)
```

By using the `executeUpdate( )` method to insert, update, and delete rows in tables. The `executeUpdate( )` method works just like the `execute()` method, except that it returns an integer value that reports the number of rows affected by the SQL statement.

The `executeUpdate` method effectively combines the `execute()` and `getUpdateCount()` methods into one call.